# HTML Div to CSS?

Tags: css, html, href

I'm trying to convert this line of HTML div to CSS. I know you can use div in CSS, but I'm unsure if you can do a href with CSS.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="menubar1">
<a href="/">Bombing</a> <a href="/pugs">Cute Pugs</a><a href="/">Bombing</a><a href="/">Bombing</a>
</div>
```

I have everything else in CSS code form, and placed using the `<style>` attribute, though I want my website to have the header on all the pages, and it'd be a hassle copy and pasting throughout the pages, especially if I get to a point where people need to post things and etc.

I appreciate all of you generosity and help!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I am also not sure, but I do know you can't do anything with `href` in CSS.

Comment: @j08691 Have an idea. `:content`?!?

Comment: how do you do div in css?

Comment: This is a scenario where the hassle you are referring to is your solution.

Comment: Look in **if** http://andydavies.me/blog/2012/08/13/what-if-we-could-use-css-to-manipulate-html-attributes/

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I don't know what mean by "converting HTML to CSS". You can't replace HTML with CSS, you can only style it.

About the other problem you're having, if you have a chunk of HTML that you want in every page you have like headers, footers, sidebars etc. you can put them on different HTML files and `require` or `include` them when needed. For example if you are using PHP that would something like:

```
<header>
    <?php require 'header.html'; ?>
</header>
<div id="content">
    <!-- content stuff... -->
</div>
<footer>
    <?php require 'footer.html'; ?>
</footer>
```